# Navigate from a TabbedPage to a ContentPage when clicked in a TabItem

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I created this tabbed Page:

```xml
        <tabView:SfTabView OverflowMode="DropDown" VisibleHeaderCount="3" EnableSwiping="True" BackgroundColor="#583068">
            <tabView:SfTabView.SelectionIndicatorSettings>
                <tabView:SelectionIndicatorSettings
                    Color="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" 
                    Position="Bottom" 
                    AnimationDuration="500"
                    StrokeThickness="2"/>
            </tabView:SfTabView.SelectionIndicatorSettings>

            <tabView:SfTabItem Title="Self Training"  TitleFontColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" SelectionColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" >
                <tabView:SfTabItem.Content>

                    <mynamespace:Self_Trainig/>
                </tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
            </tabView:SfTabItem>

            <tabView:SfTabItem Title="Programmes" TitleFontColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" SelectionColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}">
                <tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                    <mynamespace:Self_Trainig/>

                </tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
            </tabView:SfTabItem>
            <tabView:SfTabItem Title="Déconnecter">
               
            </tabView:SfTabItem>

        </tabView:SfTabView>
```

Now I need to make the "déconnecter" SfTabItem as a button which navigates to the main ContentPage.

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/tabbed-view/tabview-events#selectionchanging-in-xamarin-tabbed-view-sftabview

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TabView_SelectionChanged` event to navigate to another page. Also, make sure you have got the current name of tabview item which is `Déconnecter` and then navigate to another page. Below is the **code snippet** for your reference.

```
      private async void TabView_SelectionChanged(object sender, Syncfusion.XForms.TabView.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Name== "Déconnecter")
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
            }
        }
```